# Diophantine equation where $n<ab-a-b$ has exactly $(a-1)(b-1)/2$ solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $ax+by=n<(a-1)(b-1)$.  This has exactly $(a-1)(b-1)/2$ non-negative solutions.

I understand that $ax+by\geq (a-1)(b-1)+1$ has a non-negative solution because the spacing between solution is greater than $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.  However, in the situation $ax+by<(a-1)(b-1)$, I'm not sure how to show this has $(a-1)(b-1)/2$ non-negative solutions.  I thought this would have no solutions since it would seem like the points are too close.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62048/determining-number-of-positive-integer-solutions-to-ax-by-cz-dw-z and http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v40/issue_1/IJAM_40_1_01.pdf

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't think that's what he means. Probably he's looking for the number of integers in $[0,\,(a-1)(b-1)-1]$ that can be written as a linear combination with positive coefficients. In that case, Morris, here's my hint: try to show that $c$ has a solution if and only if $(a-1)(b-1)-1-c$ has not.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.