# Number of nonnegative solutions of linear diophantine inequality

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given inequality $Ax + By \le C$, where $A, B, C$ are integers, $A$ and $B$ are coprime and $C < AB$. I need to find number of non-negative integer solutions of it.

Is there exists algorithm which run in polynomial time?

I've read this question ([Count the number of positive solutions for a linear diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30638/count-the-number-of-positive-solutions-for-a-linear-diophantine-equation)) but given algorithm is not polynomial.

My idea is that the question is connected to Euclid algorithm and Continued fractions.

Can you help with this question giving hints/solution or links to related paper?