# Number of solutions in linear equation with 3 variables

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is there a way how to determine number of solutions in linear equation like this: $ax + by + cz = d$, where $a,b,c,x,y,z,d$ are non-negative integers and $a,b,c,d$ are known?

Comment: You can use generating functions and look at the coefficient of $X^d$ in the expansion of $(1+X^a+X^{2a}+X^{3a}+\dots)(1+X^b+X^{2b}+\dots)(1+X^c+X^{2c}+\dots)$

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30638/count-the-number-of-positive-solutions-for-a-linear-diophantine-equation) and similar ones.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$ax + by + cz = d$  -------$(1)$

For (a, b, c, d)= (3, 2, 5, 32), equation $(1)$ has parametric solution given below:

$x=(1-v)$

$y=(-5u+9v+87)$

$z=(2u-3v-29)$

For $(u,v)$ = $(15, 0)$ we get,

$(x, y, z)$ = $(1, 12, 1)$