# Combinatorial distribution

Tags: combinatorics

Need some help with this exercise:

There are $300$ students in a course. Each student can get a grade from $0-100$.
How many ways can you divide the scores to get an average of $60$?

I had struggles to isolate the scenario of the exact required average.
After that I know how to make the distribution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3050322/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: Thanks you for the remark, I've edited it :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that average of 60 implies a total score (sum of score of all students) $= 60\cdot300=18000$.

Also, let $x_i$ be the score of $i^{th}$ student. Then, $0\leq x_i\leq100$. I assume that you can only can integral grades.

Note that what you need is $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{300}=18000$

So, using generating functions, total possible ways$=$
$$\text{Coeff. of }z^{18000}\text{ in }(z^0+z^1+z^2+\cdots+z^{100})^{300}$$
$$=(\frac{z^{101}-1}{z-1})^{300}$$
$$=(z^{101}-1)^{300}\cdot(z-1)^{-300}$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{178}\binom{300}{i}\binom{300+(18000-101i)-1}{18000-101i}$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{178}\binom{300}{i}\binom{18299-101i}{18000-101i}$$
Note that I took $i\leq 178$ because $18000-101i\geq0\implies i\leq178.2$. And I'll be really honest. I don't know if there's any way to solve that summation.

Comment: I've came to something similar:

$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{300}\binom{300+18000-100j-1}{18000-100j}\binom{300}{j}(-1)^j$

Counting all the possibilities and limiting 100 for each "cell". After 180 I will just sum zeros.

Comment: There's a slight mistake. $(-1)^{18000-101j}$ will come from the other term too. So you need not include that. Further, the formula for negative binomial is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$. You seem to have missed the -1. Also, it'll be 101j and not 100j because there're 101 terms in the geometric expression and not 100 ;)

Comment: -I don't understand why -1 is not necessary.
- Yes, you are right :)
- Why 101

Comment: You've included -1 only from the $(z^{101}-1)^{300}$ term if I'm correct. But it'll be from $(z-1)^{-300}$ term too right?

Comment: Each student can a get a grade from 0 to 100. They are 101 numbers (and hence possible values of $x_i$s) and not 100

Comment: I'm taking all the distribution scenarios and eliminating all the possibilities that there will be a student with more than 100.

Comment: Can you explain why you wrote 100? May be then i can tell where r u wrong

Comment: I'm taking all the possibilities to distribute 18000 "balls" to 300 "cells". From it I'm demanding for 100 maximum balls in each cell with the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: This problem will be way easier for you to solve if you read about generating functions ;)

Comment: This is the subject of the next lecture I will have this week :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are $n$ students in a given course, and on a particular exam each student can receive an integer grade from $0$ to $100$. If the class average on the exam is exactly $60$, then how many different grade distributions are there for the students in the course?

What we are really doing is counting the solutions to a restricted Diophantine equation:
$$
s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n=n\cdot60 \quad \text{with all } s_i\in[0,100]
$$
In the case $n=1$, there is clearly only one solution. In the case $n=2$, we will have $81$ solutions, and for $n\geq 3$ it becomes clear that there are difficult counting problems involved that yield some rather large numbers.

Thankfully, this problem has been well studied; what we are really doing is counting lattice points in some high dimensional polytope, which can be accomplished with [Ehrhart polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial). In particular, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30638/count-the-number-of-positive-solutions-for-a-linear-diophantine-equation) has an answer that demonstrates how you may go about computing the answer you seek!

Answer (score 0):

The correct generating function is already given by Ankit Kumar.

So to find the exact solution, a few lines of Mathematica code is enough:

```
g = (z^101 - 1)/(z - 1);
f = g^300;
SeriesCoefficient[f, {z, 0, 18000}]
```

283842333432402321353024303661058637351420936084067738626583506213864447957870755539611750086168273196143155816656392895618438969536797685183460631860648381858482057644617263985079629258986110897789595623952660661105103107276955285902613205328147901598400715242942785403171606118195123592165718190326762039521274137278366225940884773691094689005096899697160884662108869409844236284336801805326795531698837921700003716989423475547841836096863072991222376259898318028580853239559456607248039447660955555656440250262052607092640488420986795396794284727379957951608980168883759138931179704247147