# In how many ways can you grade 5 students, so their average is 60?

Tags: combinatorics

I've been struggling with this question:

In how many ways can you grade 5 students so their average is 60? Note that each student's grade is an integer, no greater than 100 and no lower than 0.

I know that no more than 3 students can get a 100, but I don't see a way to count all the possible permutations for dividing 300 points into 5 baskets, so each of them is no more than 100 points.

I'd be grateful if you could hint me the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: What other constraints are there on the grades? I presume they need to be integers, but is this correct?

Comment: yes. i should have mentioned it.

Comment: You can adapt the technique presented in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2886015/572204) answer, but with your numbers and constraints.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: By a similar argument, you can't have more than 2 students receiving 0's. Another way to solve such a problem would be with a computer and writing a script to count all the ways

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combinatorial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050322/combinatorial-distribution)

Answer (score 1):

We can also do it by generating function.

The generating function for the same is $(1+x+x^2+.. + x^{100})^{5}$ and what we want is the coefficient of $x^{300}$.

$(1+x+x^2+.. + x^{100})^{5} = (1-x^{101})^{5}.\frac{1}{(1-x)^{5}}$

$(1-x^{101})^{5}$ can be expressed $(1-{5\choose1}x^{101} + {5\choose2}x^{202}-{5\choose3}x^{303}..$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{5}} = \sum_{0}^{\infty} {(n+5-1)\choose(5-1)}x^n$$

$\frac{1}{(1-x)^{5}} = \sum_{0}^{\infty} {(n+4)\choose(4)}x^n$

Multiplying these two expressions, you are looking to have n+4-r where r is the reducing number from the first expression. $r_i = 0, 101, 202$ for $r  i = 0,1,2$ respectively

Thus coefficients are products of $(-1)^i({5\choose i}{(300+4-r_i)\choose 4}) x^{300}$

you get ${(300+4)\choose(4)}$ for the first term

you get the next one $- {5\choose1}{(300+4-101)\choose(4)}$

and the next one ${5\choose2}{(300+4-202)\choose(4)}$

Add these products such as below

$ {304\choose4}- {5\choose1}{203\choose4}+
{5\choose2}{102\choose(4)}=47952376 $

Answer (score 0):

I just made a spreadsheet.  Start in row $101$, leaving all the ones above blank, and enter the numbers from $0$ through $300$ in column A.  That will be the sum of grades.  Now in column B enter $1$ in all the rows with numbers $0$ through $100$ in column A, which shows there is one way to give the first student any number of points from $0$ through $100$.  Now in column C in line with $0$ points enter =SUM(Left up 100:Left), where you substitute the cell references for the directions, which says the number of ways to get a sum of $0$ for the first two students is the sum of the $101$ lines ending in this one.  Copy down and right for $300$ points and $5$ students.  I find the total to be $45235674$

The generating function approach is that the function for one student is $1+x+x^2+\ldots x^{100}=\frac {1-x^{101}}{1-x}$ so the function for five students is $$\left(\frac {1-x^{101}}{1-x}\right)^5$$
and you want the coefficient of $x^{300}$ of this.  I don't have an easy way to evaluate that, but I think Mathematica can do so.

Comment: `CoefficientList[((1 - x^101)/(1 - x))^5, x][[300]]`

Comment: @David G Stork,Could you let me know how it evaluates to?

Comment: @SatishRamanathan:  48462325, but I realize that cannot be correct, because the partitions are ordered, but the students are not:  so it counts {40,50,60,70,80} as the same as {80,70,60,50,40}.  One must reduce by certain numbers of permutations.